# How should I handle string arguments in c++?

Tags: c++, string, arguments

Say I want to write a function like this:

```
int get_some_int(string index) {
    ...perform magic...
    return result;
}
```

However, I also want to be able to call it like this:

```
int var = obj.get_some_int("blah");
```

However, I can't do this as `const char[4]` is not `const string&`

I could do:

```
int get_some_int(char* index) {
    ...perform magic...
    return result;
}
```

But this spews out a lot of warnings, implying it's not how it should be done.

What is the correct way to handle string arguments then?

Comment: This should work if `std::is_same<string, std::string>::value` (which I assume to be true since I assume you use `using namespace std`, which you should not do). You probably use both `using namespace std` and you define your own type `string`, so it doesn't work.

Comment: I'll bet one of those warnings is telling you to use `const`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can't do this as const char[4] is not const string&

No, but `std::string` has a non-`explicit` conversion constructor so a temporary `std::string` is created, so you're in the clear. - http://ideone.com/xlg4k

Answer (score 1):

It should work as you have done

```
int get_some_int(string index) {  // This works as std::string has a constructor
                                  // That takes care of the conversion
                                  // from `char const*`  which you char[4] 
                                  //decays into when passed to a function
```

But a better solution would be to use a const reference:

```
int get_some_int(string const& index) {  // works for the same reasson
```

Using the const here is an indication of the how function is supposed to work and conveys information about how the input is just being used. Also when used with methods that return a a const reference to a string (say from a const object) it will still work as expected.

Comment: @Are you sure. Usually this will be a temporary inside the function (if you are building the real index). But if so then use the initial value version.

Answer (score 0):

Do a:

int var = obj.get_some_int(string("blah"));

if you feel more comfortable with it.